# Field enabled based on role

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm struggling to get a field to be enabled and/or visible based on user's role in Google App Maker.

I'm assigned to the Admins role and am trying to get the field to enable and/or visible if an Admin is the user of the page.

On the object i've added the below to the enabled and visible option

@user.roles ? "Admins"

but it's permenantly disabled. I've tried testing as both preview and published versions. I've also tried seeing it as @user.roles ? Admins and it still stays disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be (@user.roles).indexOf('Admins') > -1. Bracket placement seems to be very particular when using visibility or enabled when using a binding in app maker.

Comment: This works. Thanks very much both of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set binding to:

(@user.roles).indexOf('Admins') > -1

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing it wrong, but it won't let me enter this. I've tried setting it as the Binding option of Enabled, but it won't let me click OK. I've looked at the options of user.roles and I only have .length

Comment: Try to wrap it with brackets: (@user.roles.indexOf('Admins')) > -1 or (@user.roles.indexOf('Admins') > -1)